# Revoke privileges from user in mySQL

Tags: mysql, privileges, mysqladmin, mysqladministrator

For every new user we create in mySQL using the statement

```
CREATE USER newuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

"SHOW GRANTS" is showing only "USAGE ON *.* " privilege.

But the user is able to select,insert,.. on "test" and "information_schema" databases and I'm unable to revoke these privileges on "test" using the revoke statement given below.

```
REVOKE ALL ON test.* FROM newuser@localhost;
ERROR 1141 (42000) : There is no such grant defined for user 'guest' on host 'localhost'
```

I just don't want the newuser to access the test and information_schema databases.

Comment: What about deleting the user and creating it again with `GRANT ... ON <Schema name>.*` instead of `*.*` ?

Comment: I tried " grant usage on database.* to newuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; " but still its granting for all databases ie "usage on \*.*" for the new user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html

> By default, the `mysql.db` table contains rows that permit access by
>   any user to the `test` database and other databases with names that
>   start with `test_`. (...) This means that
>   such databases can be used even by accounts that otherwise possess no
>   privileges. If you want to remove any-user access to test databases,
>   do so as follows:
>
> ```
> mysql> DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db LIKE 'test%';
> mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> ```
>
> (...)
>   With the preceding change, only users who have global database
>   privileges or privileges granted explicitly for the test database can
>   use it.

The `information_schema` database is a read-only pseudo database built on-the-fly on request. Users will always be able to consult this database, but it only presents entries to which they already have access to otherwise.