# Mysql account denying access to certain DB

Tags: mysql

I am hoping to create a mysql user account which can access everything but one secret DB. I understand how to create a account to access specific db, but deny to access to anything else. But I don't know how to do it the other way around.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98949/grant-select-on-all-databases-except-one-mysql

Comment: Thanks. So there is not an easy way to exclude certain database(s), is it correct? If this is the case, I may have to do it in the application. My application allows users to dynamically create their own db, but I don't want the users to access the metadata db owned by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a straightforward way.  But here is an automated way:

Use the mysql commandline tool.

1. Give the user a login ("USAGE"), something like:

   `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'most'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd';`
2. *Generate* the rest of the grants:

   `SELECT DISTINCT`
   `CONCAT('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.* TO most@localhost;')`
   `FROM information_schema.TABLES`
   `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA`
   `NOT IN('mysql', 'performance_schema', 'information_schema', 'secret');`
3. Copy & paste them to execute them.

(Change 'most', 'localhost', 'pwd', 'secret' as needed.)

Comment: You may need to schedule this #2 as a SP and an event to periodically grant access to new DB's. This is a common problem with sharding while preventing access to mysql.*. I found a 1 minute EVENT was sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I tried it, but the `information_schema` is still visible.

Comment: I read it from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247590/revoke-privileges-from-user-in-mysql `information_schema` is a read-only pseudo database built on-the-fly on request. Users will always be able to consult this database, but it only presents entries to which they already have access to otherwise.

Comment: Good point about the I_S.  P_S might follow the same logic.  However, `mysql` should be given no more than `SELECT`, and even that is risky because of what a hacker can get from the list of users, etc.